# Linking to a static file from within statics in Expressjs

Tags: node.js, express

I've got a weird issue which I can't seem to figure out with expressjs. I've specified a `public` folder for all static files such as js, css and images. I'm using `app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));` to specify the folder. This works perfectly except for one case.

Inside the public folder, I've got 3 folders called `js`, `css` and `images`. Within one of my css files, I'm doing `background-image: url(/images/bg.png) no-repeat;` but this url is not resolving and the image is not showing on the page.

However, if I do something like `img(src='/images/bg.png')` from within one of my views, the image shows. I'm assuming that this has to do with the fact that I'm linking from a static file and node/express are ignoring all routes(?) from within the static files.

How would one go about linking to images in css files located inside a static folder in express?

Comment: what happens when you simply go to `127.0.0.1:yourport/images/bg.png` ?

Comment: Look at the real path css is looking in or maybe turn the css compiler off.

Comment: @generalhenry The image shows at this URL.

Comment: @Raynos The path css is looking at is localhost:3000/images/bg.png

Comment: @Vahe I mean if you go to your website and look in the resources tab (chrome) what image is returning the 404. What URL is it actually looking at and failing.

Comment: Stupid mistake on my part guys. The problem was with the no-repeat statement in css. Changing it to `background: #fff url(/images/bg.png) no-repeat;` fixes the issue. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Your CSS urls are relitive to the STYLESHEET so the url you have is looking for the path `/css/images/bg.png` you want to have the url be `../images/bg.png`